# Django model blank=False does not work?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model in Django 1.5:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Note that according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/
name.blank is by default False which means it must be specified.

However, I could successfully create a Person object as follows:

```
Person.objects.create()
```

Notice the name is not specified. What is going on?

Ok, the answer from the docs is :

> Note that this is different than null. null is purely database-related, whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has blank=True, *form validation* will allow entry of an empty value.  If a field has blank=False, the field will be required.

Another catch:

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a  ModelForm, it will run your validators on any fields that are included in your form.
>
> It's your responsibility to call the clean methods before saving if you're not using a form.

Comment: Firstly, whats up with this `name                     = ...` Do NOT do this.

Comment: I believe Games is referring to the indentation. It is not recommended coding practice per PEP-8.

Comment: @bernie Yes, exactly what I was trying to get at.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`blank` only applies to form field validation as in the admin, django forms, etc.
`null` on the other hand is a database level nullable column.

As for why blank results in a default `''`, I had really just accepted it as "that's the way it works" but here's where it appears to be in `django.db.models.Field`

```
  def get_default(self):
        """
        Returns the default value for this field.
        """
        if self.has_default():
            if callable(self.default):
                return self.default()
            return force_unicode(self.default, strings_only=True)
        if (not self.empty_strings_allowed or (self.null and
                   not connection.features.interprets_empty_strings_as_nulls)):
            return None
        return ""  
        #       ^ this
```

Comment: I never knew that. Learnt something new.

Comment: This is so outrageous. Indeed it seems that there needs to be some manual checking when creation is made on backend... Another possible fix is to set default=None for those CharFields.

Answer (score 0):

Django creates your user with an empty string. You can actually run `Person.objects.all()` and it will give you a list, if you save that to a variable called `user_list` and do something like `user_list[0]`, it will return a user object with an empty string. I do not know how or why it does this.